# Pie chart resizing on some displays each refresh

Tags: javascript, charts

There are many questions out there relating to issues with chart.js re-sizing charts if the same canvas is reused (on some devices).  Most of the answers refer to the fact that you need to "destroy" the chart before reusing.

```
pie = new Chart(pieContext).Pie(data);
```

and then next time, before doing the above call

```
pie.destroy();
```

And in hindsight, this appears to work.  However, I had already moved onto using ChartNew.js (https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/) as it seems to have some enhanced functionality above (and was based on) chart.js.

NewChart.js experiences the same 're-sizing' issue, but does NOT seem to provide a destroy() method on the chart object.

How do I fix the re-sizing issue?  Is there a destroy() equivalent on ChartNew.js?

Or.. Is there an alternative free library that will allow me to display Pie charts, with the data values written inside the segments and a legend down the right-hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read a couple of posts to the developer or `ChartNew.js` and it seems like functions like `destroy()` or `clean()` are missing from the original Chart.js

Now, I'm not familiar with the library but maybe this [thread](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/issues/172) lights up one of your lightbulbs.

Sorry if not very useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems as though the author has written an updateChart() function, which I thought was going to fix it.  But the chart still re-sizes.  I may have to look at a new chart library.

Comment: :( Yes, I'm afraid you may have to change it, or maybe try to contact the author? I hope you find your way man :)

Comment: It was not fixed, in the end I removed and re-added the canvas each refresh and now it works.

Comment: Oh you got me on an emotional rollercoaster hahaha, I'm glad in the end you figured it out :)